# I need properly increment a function in JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, html

Please bear with me. I'm working on the following loop and I'm trying to figure out why foo.count is never incremented and displays 0. I would like to rewrite the example so that foo.count is properly incremented. I know I'm overlooking something. Any suggestions?
Thanks

```
function foo(num) {
  console.log("foo: " + num);
  this.count++;
}
foo.count = 0;

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i > 5) {
    foo(i);
  }
}
// foo: 6 
// foo: 7 
// foo: 8 
// foo: 9 
console.log(foo.count); // Still 0!
```

Comment: in the context of the code you posted, this.count is not foo.count - you need to learn how `this` works - in this example, if you always use `foo.count` you'll be golden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @Jaromanda X Thanks for the input! I overlooked the use of "this".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Jaromanda, you're utilizing `this` incorrectly. In this scenario, you need to be careful where you use it. Try replacing `this.count++` with `foo.count++`

```
function foo(num) {
  console.log("foo: " + num);
  foo.count++;
}
foo.count = 0;

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i > 5) {
    foo(i);
  }
}
// foo: 6 
// foo: 7 
// foo: 8 
// foo: 9 
console.log(foo.count); // Still 0!
```

Note that using `this` references the object it is contained within, not the function in is contained within, as it appears you mistakenly have taken it for. When referencing the object that is currently contained, it is necessary to use the 'this' operator, not only for clarity, but also to avoid potential ambiguity.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you've written, if you were to `console.log(this)` inside your `foo()` function, you'd see that it prints the `window` object.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this); // prints "window" and/or attributes
}
foo();
```

You've created a `count` variable on both the `window` and bolted onto the side of the `foo()` function. However, being attached TO the function isn't the same thing as being *inside* the function's scope.

So that `foo.count` variable never gets incremented since it's different from `this.count` (which is on `window`).

Answer (score 0):

```
//"this" is window object. In the following code, I have replaced "foo.count" by "count".
  function foo ( num ) { 
        console.log ( "foo: " + num );
        this.count++; 
        }

            count = 0; 
            var i; 
            for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++ ) { 
            if ( i > 5 ) { 
            foo ( i ); 
            } 
        } 
        // foo: 6 
        // foo: 7 
        // foo: 8 
        // foo: 9 
        console.log ( foo.count ); // Still 0!
```